# Ways to communicate from Android to PC?

Tags: android

I am building an app that requires realtime data generated on an Android to be available to an application running on a PC. I suspect that network calls to a web service would be too slow. What other protocols/technologies exist? Bluetooth? Is there a good API for communicating over the USB connection? (Although it would be nice not to have to do that.)

Comment: "I suspect that the network calls would be too slow" You may be right but why not just try anyway. For all we know it might be premature optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno about bluetooth, I'd try to use the network somehow.

The fastest, realtime way over a network would be to use 'Socket Programming' (peer-to-peer) between your android and a PC. Networks are plenty fast. People play real-time first person shooters against eachother this way. I doubt you'd have more data to transfer than that.

If you don't need realtime perhaps you can utilize a web service.

Comment: Bluetooth is a networking technology, it just happens to be a local-only network.  You're actually going to see lower throughput over Bluetooth than over Wi-Fi.

Comment: What would be some good documentation for how to do socket programming between a Java app on the PC and an Android app?

Answer (score 0):

I havent really seen any mention of usb connection to the pc using app anywhere, but you might want to try network based connection locally (using wifi) which might speed up the network connectivity. And i am not totally sure about this, but android ndk -> http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html might be useful in this case. Good luck :)